# Dynamic place label filtering

Tags: google-maps, mapbox, mapzen

I’m working on a map that shows local names and translated place names (e.g., “Deutschland” and “Germany”) at the same time. A very rough Mapbox prototype is posted at http://www.svexit.com/realnameatlas.html, but I’m open to trying this using Mapzen, Google Maps, or others

I’m trying to figure out if it’s possible / the best way to dynamically filter out place labels when they’re the same (e.g., “United Kingdom” in English is still “United Kingdom” or “Hamburg”, which doesn’t have a separate English translation, but has translations in Russian, French, Spanish, and Chinese). The goal is to leverage the existing translations and not maintain my own separate data set.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this Mapzen blog post shows something similar here with Tangram:

https://mapzen.com/blog/languages-of-india/

Because the name data is processed as a JavaScript object, you should be able to filter out any duplicates before drawing the labels.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to meetar pointing me in the right direction (and some additional spelunking here to check for "undefined"), I was able to suppress undefined English-language labels using the following:

```
            text_source: |
                function() {
                    if (typeof feature["name:en"] === "undefined") {
                    return feature["name"]; 
                            }
                    else {
                    return feature["name"] + '\n(' + feature["name:en"] + ')'; 
                        }
                    }
```